# python3 summarize elements form list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sublist

I have a list of lists

```
lst = [[0,1],[1,1],[3,1],[1,2],[1,3],[3,5]]
```

I want to summarize the second items of the sublists for equal first items. The result should look like

```
lst = [[0,1],[1,6],[3,6]]
```

I tried something like this:

```
lst=[[0, 0.25], [1, 0.125], [2, 0.0625], [3, 0.0625], [1, 0.125], [2, 0.0625], [3, 0.03125], [4, 0.03125]]
for listitem in range(len(lst)):
    first=listitem[0]
    second = 0
    for obj in lst:
        if obj[0] == first:
            second += obj[1]
            lst.remove(obj)
    listitem[1] = second
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using defaultdict

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    lst=[[0, 0.25], [1, 0.125], [2, 0.0625], [3, 0.0625], [1, 0.125], [2, 0.0625], [3, 0.03125], [4, 0.03125]]

    res = defaultdict(int)    
    for el in lst:
        res[el[0]] += el[1] 
    res_list = [[k,v] for (k,v) in res.items()]

    print(res_list)

[[0, 0.25], [1, 0.25], [2, 0.125], [3, 0.09375], [4, 0.03125]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`groupby` returns a key and iterator over the items with the same key.  It must be passed a list sorted by the same key:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[0,1],[1,1],[3,1],[1,2],[1,3],[3,5]]

result = [[k,sum(b for a,b in g)]
           for k,g in groupby(sorted(lst),key=itemgetter(0))]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
 [[0, 1], [1, 6], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about this is that the first item in each pair is the `key`, and the second is the `value` -- so if you create a `dict` you can then add the values together as you come across each key -- and it's even easier if you use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

summary = defaultdict(int)
for sublist in lst:
    key, value = sublist
    summary[key] += value

print(summary.items())
```

The line `summary[key] += value` is the workhorse here.  What it does:

- looks up the `key` in summary
- if it doesn't exist add it and use `int` to create the default value
- return the value (either already there or freshly created)
- add the new value to it
- store it back to `summary` under `key`

Answer (score 0):

`range(n)` produces a list such as `[0,1,2...n-1]`, so the type of `listitem` is `int` rather than `list`.

```
lst=[[0, 0.25], [1, 0.125], [2, 0.0625], [3, 0.0625], [1, 0.125], [2, 0.0625], [3, 0.03125], [4, 0.03125]]
for listitem in lst:
    first = listitem[0]
    second = 0
    for obj in lst:
        if obj[0] == first:
            second += obj[1]
            lst.remove(obj)
    listitem[1] = second
```